# iOS Autolayout : Give top space equal to 1/5 of superview height

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I want to set top space of my label to 1/5 of super view height. I know we can do this at runtime by changing the constant to 1/5 of super view. But I want to do this using XIB only. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: use spacerview and give equal height with multiplier ... thats it  .. or if you are using ios9 or later than use stackview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed @EI Captain,

We need to use spacer view. @Mohammad, please have a look at constraints I have given to space view and label. it will definitely solve your issue.

Attaching screen shot for you! enjoy.

[image: SpacerView]

[image: Your Label]

Comment: thanks. This should work. So there is no direct way to achieve this using multiplier. Will have to live extra view just for constraint. :(

Answer (score 2):

A complicated way is to calculate the align to vertical center
[image]

128 = (600 - 20) * 0.2
so we set 0.6 to the multiplier

Comment: But I would use @EI Captain's idea in real case

Answer (score 0):

Programatic version of accepted answer is something like

```
let spacerFromTop = UILayoutGuide()
superview.addLayoutGuide(spacerFromTop)
spacerFromTop.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
spacerFromTop.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true

button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacerFromTop.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Where button is the thing I want 80% from top and superview is the, um, superview. Use `0.2` for 1/5, of course.